# ExtJS Export Excel SaveDocumentAs Issue

Tags: extjs

When I attempt to export using a function I get this below error on Sencha.

I have below in the file:

```
   requires: [
        'AppName.view.main.MainController',
        'Ext.exporter.text.CSV',
        'Ext.grid.plugin.Exporter',
        'Ext.ux.grid.SubTable',
        'Overrides.exporter.excel.Xlsx',
    ],
    plugins: [{
        ptype: 'gridexporter'
    }],
```

I still cannot export XLSX files...

[image]

Error is for the line : this.getView().saveDocumentAs({

Code

```
onExportList2: function () {
    var filters = '';
    var cm = this.getView().headerCt;

    if (cm) {
        Ext.each(cm.gridDataColumns, function(col, index) {
            var field = this.lookup(col.dataIndex + 'FilterField');
            if (field && !Ext.isEmpty(field.getValue())) {
                if (!Ext.isEmpty(filters)) filters += ', ';
                filters += col.text + ': ' + (col.exportRenderer ? col.exportRenderer(field.getValue()) : field.getValue());
            }
        }, this);
    }

    this.getView().saveDocumentAs({
        type: 'xlsx',
        title: 'Account Change',
        subtitle1: filters,
        fileName: 'Account Change Requests.xlsx'
    });
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far closest I came to finding the answer is when I did the testing to a portion of my app that has this functionality working already. I removed the below code from it, then I started getting this error on that as well. So I am thinking it might be related to grid exporter is not working but no resolution yet.

```
"plugins: [{
                ptype: 'gridexporter'
            }],"
```

Answer (score 2):

replace `Overrides.exporter.excel.Xlsx` with `Ext.exporter.excel.Xlsx`.

`Overrides.exporter.excel.Xlsx` would in best case change the behavior of it.

why it crashes is difficult to tell, unless having seen `MainController.js` at line `400`.

Comment: I updated, still error. Also error line just updated my question with it. Its giving an error on saveDocumentAs

Comment: @Peace think the reason is the `this.getView()`. this needs to be an ExtJS component; eg. `Ext.ComponentQuery.query('grid')[0]` (in order to get a handle to the first one data-grid there - which is probably the only type of component, which would translate to `XLSX`).

Comment: It sounds like though SaveDocumentAs not being recognized as a function...

Comment: @Peace if the context of `this` is a data-grid, it might be `this.saveDocumentAs()`.

Comment: It's still giving an error: Uncaught TypeError: this.saveDocumentAs is not a function

Comment: Weird part of this is that, same app has elsewhere fully working excel export... I just cant get it to work for this part.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add the Exporter package to your app.json requires section.

put requires in your controller:

```
requires: [
    'Ext.exporter.text.CSV',
    'Ext.exporter.excel.Xlsx'
],
```

put plugin and requires in your view:

```
plugins: {
    gridexporter: true
},
requires: [
    'Ext.grid.plugin.Exporter'
],
```